# How do I access all data from a SQL query where left join is used?

Tags: c#, database, tableadapter

I'm creating a method that populates some textboxes with data retrieved from an Access database using table adapters.

The `GetCasesWithUserFromCaseId` method return a single case with the `username` which is found by left joining my cases table with my users table.

For some reason I get a NullReferenceException when trying to access the joined data (userdata) from the users table but data from the cases table works. I'm sure that all fields is set for all users and all cases-tablerows.

If this doesn't work how do I then alternately get my data? I've attached an image showing my simple database.

The sql-statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM cases
LEFT JOIN users ON cases.caseCreatedBy = users.userId
WHERE caseId = caseNum
```

The C# code:

```
public void populateBoxes(int caseId)
{
   caseDBTableAdapters.casesTableAdapter casesAdapter = 
        new caseDBTableAdapters.casesTableAdapter();
   caseDB.casesDataTable cases;
   cases = casesAdapter.GetCasesWithUserFromCaseId(caseId);

   foreach (caseDB.casesRow casesRow in cases)
   {
      tbCaseName.Text = casesRow.caseName;
      tbOwner.Text = casesRow.usersRow.firstName.ToString();
   }
}
```

[image: database layout]

[image]

Comment: And what sql are you using to access the tables?

Comment: Sorry - just a sec then i'll update with the exception.

Comment: @Marc_s - Its a NullReferenceException

Comment: @Marc_s - Could this happen when I create the tableadapter? i'm not using a sql-statement using join then, so the tableadapter doesn't hold the joined field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the point is: if you do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on your `Users` table, then this statement here is dangerous:

```
foreach (caseDB.casesRow casesRow in cases)
{
    tbCaseName.Text = casesRow.caseName;
    tbOwner.Text = casesRow.usersRow.firstName.ToString();  <== !!!!!
}
```

With a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, there's a chance that there are no users for your case - so `casesRow.usersRow` would be null.

You need to check for that!

```
foreach (caseDB.casesRow casesRow in cases)
{
    tbCaseName.Text = casesRow.caseName;

    if(casesRow.usersRow != null)
    {
        tbOwner.Text = casesRow.usersRow.firstName.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes the NullReferenceException not happen. But still i'm getting no userdata for any row. And when i do a "Preview" data" it returns the data correctly. I've added an image to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the GetCasesWithUserFromCaseId() method is joining the cases and users tables with a left join.  Is the exemption you are getting a NullReferenceExemption?

I would guess that the output of your access method is resulting in

```
caseName    firstName
----------  ----------
Bildsoe     NULL
```

if that is the case, then in your code line:

```
tbOwner.Text = casesRow.usersRow.firstName.ToString();
```

the usersRow property of the casesRow is likely to be null.  You will have to check if the property is null before you try to reference it.

Comment: @Nathan - this is not the case, im sure that firstName has a value for all rows.